# Rocket.Chat client for CentOS 6

Tags: centos6, rocket.chat

Is it possible to compile Rocket.Chat client for CentOS 6?
Or can I already download it from somewhere?

Any documentation how can I compile Rocket.Chat client?

Answer (score 0):

You can download rpm package for rocket.chat from here https://rocket.chat/download .And install it as `rpm -i package_name.rpm`.

Comment: unfortunately, there is only for centos 7 available.